# What are the pros and cons of creating a new class?

Tags: oop

This is a probably a very basic question, but it's one I'm actually running into as I'm learning more about Actionscript 3 in particular. However, my first question is very general: When is appropriate to put functionality in a new class rather than a new function in the same class? According to this [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html), which focuses on basic object-oriented principles, a class is supposed to be a "blueprint of an object". I always understood this to mean that any functionality or behavior that the object would use should be contained within the class. However, according to the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), each class should have only one reason to change. For example, you should have one class to compile a report and one class to print it rather than a single Report class.

Can you guys help me understand the pros and cons to creating a new class? What are the costs to splitting an object into multiple classes? Are there compile-time or performance costs for keeping related functionality in the same class, or for splitting it into two? Are there perhaps times that you would want to split things out, while you might want to keep them together other times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, there isn't a *big* difference between having 1 class which can do everything or several classes which can do the same.

It's about readability and how you can extend the code. It's also just about clean code and coupling.

If you have a class called "Printer" you don't want to have "WaterCoolerSound()" in it. Of course the more objects you have the higher the chance is that you can run out of memory. But I am not entirely sure whether one object with all functionality or several classes with the same functionality spread out, takes more memory.

In fact, you could say that if you JUST need a little bag to hold on to some data and not be able to dance like a bear at the same time, it would make sense to have two separate classes.

It's advisable not to think about the performance before you have the code. From the maintainability and understandability viewpoint, of course, smaller classes, with smaller methods are superior. (see The Single Responsibility Principle again :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't get so confused about making classes for just a function. A class should have only related functions.If the functions are of different kinds which will do totally different functionalities and use totally different kind of variables then only u should make a separate class.

Comment: One of the reasons that this question came up for me is that one of my personal projects I am working on is a game. I have all the logic coded in, and am now essentially creating the GUI. Would it be better to have all the image and event creation in a separate class? I guess that's getting into actionscript specific, which I was trying to avoid with this question...