# Pros and Cons of creating a separate class for the GUI (in actionscript)

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

This is related to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597159/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-creating-a-new-class)  I just asked; however, this one is specifically tailored to my individual project, rather than object-oriented programming in general.

I am working on a version of hangman with some interesting programming twists. I don't need to go into detail of what they are as the logic for the game is already finished. I can run an entire game by hard-coding variables for the user input (such as guess selection). I am now in the process of replacing all those bits that require user interaction with the trappings of an actual game like buttons, images, sounds, etc.

I am trying to figure out whether it is better to have all of this stuff be part of my main class, or whether I should create another class to handle it all. For example, I want my players to be able to click on an on-screen keyboard to make their guess, with each button firing a separate event listener call to the makeGuess function. Would it be better to create the buttons as direct children of my main game class, or should I create a subclass (called Keyboard, for example) that creates the keyboard section of the board with the appropriate events, then add the keyboard class as a child to the main rather than all the pieces? What are the pros and cons of each of these choices?

For the record, I'm programming using FlashDevelop, so nothing like a timeline for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I say you'd better create at least the `Keyboard` class that will parse the events fired by tapping/clicking keys inside, and give it a callback reference to your `Main` class, or `GameLogic` class, so that it can do `theMain.guess(letter);` and then the `Main` class logic will come to life and process the callback. Since this structure is not exactly related to game logic, and technically it can then be reused by implementing an interface for the callback, so that you can use this keyboard elsewhere where you want to have your player to type letters using mouse, it's better be separated from main logic.

```
public class Keyboard extends Sprite {
    public var callback:AcceptingKeys; // an interface
    ... // class implementation, with all the listeners, children and stuff
    // and you call in there: callback.acceptKey(key);
}
public interface AcceptingKeys {
    public function acceptKey(key:String):void; // or whatever type you need
}
```

And you do with your `Main` class:

```
public class Main extends Sprite
implements AcceptingKeys {
     ...
     var keyboard:Keyboard;
     private function init(e:Event=null):void {
         ... // other code. It's FD, then this function exists
         keyboard=new Keyboard();
         keyboard.callback=this;
         // past this point your instances can talk
     }
     public function acceptKey(key:String):void {
         // match interface description
         ... // do game logic for parsing a key
     }
}
```